# Use border radius on box-shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css

The result of the code below is this image:

[image]

Problem is that not all corners have border radius. This is due to the fact that the parent has a max-width and the border-radius only applies to the ends of the span.

Is there a workaround? Maybe with JS? To detect every new line and add another span with a background with border radius? Because of responsiveness I cannot add breaks in the span. On the desktop version it's one long line.

```css
h1 span {
    background-color: #272e3a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #272e3a, -20px 0 0 #272e3a;
    box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #272e3a, -20px 0 0 #272e3a;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 58px;
    color:white !important;
}

h1 {
    color: white !important;
    max-width: 400px;
}

body {
    padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></h1>

</body
```

**Question:** How to make all corners have border radius? Without editing the html?

Comment: This would actually be a use case for [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) (instead of the box-shadow _workaround_) ... but IE/Edge still can’t be bothered.

Answer (score 5):

Got the solution. I had to add

```
box-decoration-break: clone;
```

and

```
word-break: break-word;
```

```css
h1 span {
    background-color: #272e3a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #272e3a, -20px 0 0 #272e3a;
    box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #272e3a, -20px 0 0 #272e3a;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size:40px;
    line-height: 58px;
    color:white !important;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    word-break: break-word;
}

h1 {
    color: white !important;
    max-width: 400px;
}

body {
    padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></h1>

</body
```